# How to regoup in subdocuments, multi document that have a same field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in **mongoDB** that looks like this :

```
db.mycollection.find({}) 

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4ce4bbe1b67e6e5611e4"),
    "site" : "MDC",
    "label" : "407",
    "status" : "removed"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5def36379ca17632de773d7e"),
    "site" : "MDC",
    "label" : "407",
    "status" : "new"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df4740eab0d76657c19a7d2"),
    "site" : "MDC",
    "label" : "408",
    "status" : "new"
}
```

I would like to regroup my documents that have the same value for the field "label" in one document with subdocument of the status, to have something like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5deb4ce4bbe1b67e6e5611e4"),
    "site" : "MDC",
    "label" : "407",
    "status" : [ 
    {
        "label" : "new"
    }, 
    {
        "label" : "removed"
    }
]
}
```

I tried different ways (aggregate, update,..) to do this but it's a complete fail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `$group` by `label` or `site` in order to `$push` your statuses:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$label",
            old_id: { $first: "$_id" },
            site: { $first: "$site" },
            status: { $push: { label: "$status" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$old_id",
            site: 1,
            label: "$_id",
            status: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ulNzpRMdnK2)